# Change Cmake generator in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cmake, iar, nmake

There's alot going on here that may be affecting this but the simple question is this - How can I change the generator that Eclipse passes to cmake when I build my project? It always defaults to "MinGW Makefiles" when what I want is "NMake Makefiles".

The backstory (complicated) is a project was imported from IAR Embedded Workbench. I created a new build configuration to try and build using cmake instead (which works fine from a command line).

Eclipse Version: Photon (4.8)
Current Toolchain: IAR Toolchain for ARM - (8.x)
Current Builder: CMake Builder (portable)

Answer (score 0):

> I created a new build configuration to try and build using cmake instead (which works fine from a command line)

From the quote (above):
Assuming you want to build an IAR Project that was imported into eclipse from the command line (for continous Integration), then I can recommend to call the whole eclipse build from the command line. (This might help: [Untegrating an eclipse/cdt-based build into continuous integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119680/untegrating-an-eclipse-cdt-based-build-into-continuous-integration) and official documentation: https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)